# With BeautifulSoup 4 (lxml parser), how do I extract inner HTML from a tag (decode_contents not working)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, innerhtml

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 and Python 3.7.  I want to extract the inner HTML from a found article.  I have this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
...
article_elt = top_article_elt.select('div[class*="outer"]')[0]
article = article_elt.decode_contents()
...
print("article: " + str(article) + " score:" + str(score))
```

However, what is getting printed out includes the outer tags ...

```
article: <div class="outer"><p>Top story of the year.</p>
</div>
```

How do I write a statement that extracts only the inner HTML?

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: have you checked what article_elt actually contains?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, "article_elt" begins with '<div class="outer">'.  I would only like the stuff inside there (the inner HTML?, not sure if I'm using the right terminology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick fix could be to just go one level deep with `.find()`:

```
article = article_elt.find().decode_contents()
```

---

But, this might just be treating a symptom and not the problem itself. It feels like it is either that you have nested `div` elements with `class="outer"` or, the `class*="outer"` check matches some unexpected elements up the tree. Try:

```
article_elt = top_article_elt.select_one('div.outer')
```

Comment: Well when I replaced my statement with what you have, "top_article_elt.select_one('div.outer')", that succeeded in stripping off those outer DIV tags.